# Cannot install gfortran on Ubuntu 16.04 despite a myriad of attempted solutions

Tags: 16.04, package-management, software-installation, dependencies

I tried to install gfortran on Ubuntu 16.04.3 with `sudo apt install gfortran` but I got the following error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
Some packages could not be installed.  
This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you  
are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not
yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. 
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies: gfortran : 
  Depends: gfortran-5 (>= 5.3.1-3~) but it is not going to be installed  
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried apt, aptitude, cleaning, updating, upgrading and fixing potential broken dependencies all to no avail. I was hoping to diagnose this problem another way.

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you using?  A quick scan of https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=gfortran-5&searchon=names makes it look like it's available.  You also have broken packages - so did you try the suggested solution?  (`sudo apt -f install`)  You should fix prior problems before you try and add new packages.  You haven't pasted to your question the real error you need to fix though so we can't help with that.

Comment: Im using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. I did try sudo apt - f install aswell prior to trying to install fortran.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.4 came out in March 1, 2018 - so you're Ubuntu hasn't been full-upgraded since at least then. Your first priority should be to bring your system up-to-date by fixing your held broken packages, and installing security updates (and I'd suggest taking note of problems & error messages rather than just letting your system stop upgrading)

Comment: Ill update the system and see if it works. I thought by doing a apt-get upgrade actually upgrades the system.

Comment: fyi:  `apt-get upgrade` does upgrade within certain restrictions.  Many changes however get 'skipped' to ensure no reboot /stability/.. is attained. 
 The man page states "dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade, also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions of packages"  and doesn't leave packages un-upgraded/skipped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Ubuntu 16.04.3 hasn't been updated in a long time, so you should do a software update before trying to fix the broken packages.

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt upgrade
```

Select the *Fix Broken Packages* option in Synaptic package manager. It's a GUI solution to the broken packages error message that's easy to do.

Run the following command to install Synaptic.

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install synaptic
```

Open Synaptic and in Synaptic select *Edit* -> ***Fix Broken Packages*** and then repeat *Edit* -> *Fix Broken Packages* a second time.

Another easy fix is to install an older version of gfortran from the default Ubuntu 16.04 repositories instead of the *gfortran* package which is currently version 5.3.1. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install gfortran-4.8
```

Comment: Synaptic didnt work but installing gfortran-4.8 did work. I see the reason why the latest gfortran doesn't install is because as @guiverc pointed out, my system is out of date